# When does a substructure of an algebraic structure exist? (from Fraleigh)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read in Fraleigh, A first course in Abstract Algebra, that

> If we have a set, together with a certain type of algebraic structure (groups, rings, integral domains, etc.), then any subset of this set, together with a natural induced algebraic structure that yields an algebraic structure of the same type, is a substructure.

I am trying to understand this comment. Firstly, why does Fraleigh say "algebraic structure" instead of something like "algebraic operation"? Also, if we have, say, an integral domain $D$ and $A$ is a subdomain of $D$, then is it reasonable to infer, form this above comment, that $A$ is an integral domain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An operation is something like addition or multiplication.  An algebraic structure is a lot more than that. Typically an algebraic structure is defined by one or more operations together with axioms they must satisfy.  There are group axioms, ring axioms, etc., which define a group, ring, etc.  It is a lot more than just an operation.

Yes, in that case, $A$ would also be an integral domain.